Как создать exe файл с sqllite3 и испольняемым файлом main.py
В созданном проекте используется база данных, но при создании exe файла через PyInstaller и запуске программы базы данных нет и данных с нее соответственно тоже.
Как можно сделать так, чтоб внутри exe файла была база данных и она могла дополняться
Пробовал несколько способов создания exe файла, но все безуспешно.
Файл базы данных создается в той директории где и находится исполняемый файл, но не внутри exe файла

Внутри никак, разве что не планируется изменение файла БД.

Теоретически наверное возможно, но это настолько геморно, что я бы не брался. Pyinstaller создает exe файл, где первая часть - пусковой файл, вторая часть - zip архив. При запуске пусковой файл распаковывает интерпретатор и программу в байт-коде во временную папку. Можно теоретически писать файл базы данных в эту же папку, но автоматом оно обратно само себя не упакует. Придется вручную сжимать в zip архив, удалять из исходного exe все лишнее, клеить полученный zip в конец exe. Но не факт что получится, пока исходный exe запущен. В общем, слишком много гемора.

А куда тогда можно прятать эту бд от пользователя?

@Андрей а зачем её прятать?

@Amgarak там хранятся пароли пользователей, они не должны их видеть

@Андрей а что помешает пользователю вскрыть запакованный .exe (по факту это архив) и вытащить оттуда файл бд?!) Вам явно нужно переосмыслить работу с вашей БД.
